# How to Show files in browser instead of download using laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show files (pdf, docx etc) in browser once click on a button instead of download.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please update your post to include the code that you're using right now and the solutions you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: Travis Britz i tried multiple solutions for it using google but find nothing, so i asked here

Comment: @AleemZada if you have tried something, you should describe that, you'll save your time and ours.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used the google docs to view pdf files.

here is my code --

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/gview?url={{ URL::to($tableof1->content) }}" target="_blank">{{$tableof1->content_title}}</a>
```

Comment: what if i want to show word document sir ?

Comment: yes, you can open word documents in google docs

Answer (score 3):

`file()` method is used to display an image or PDF directly in user's browser.

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

or

```
return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
```

Read this more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#other-response-types)

Comment: from controller, i am returning information for a book, in view i'm displaying book information like book name, book category and i have a path to the Book. i have displayed the book in <a> anchor tag. how i can show the path of book to preview in browser instead of download

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, you can try to display file type like images and pdf using `return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);`

but you **can not show docx** file directly in the browser. You need some kind of conversion which browser can support in order to show docx onto the browser